# How to revert permissons of /media/username directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, media

I, by mistake, ran the command:

`sudo chown -R username:username /media/username/*`

While I intended to run:

`sudo chown -R username:username /media/username/586e1a3e-80c3-4057-81bz7-bbfe7662c6ff`

How can I revert the permissions of the `/media/username` directory and its contents?

Comment: That command is valid for a removable media. If you want to revert either restore a backup or you will need to use `chmod` with the correct username and usergroup for each file and directory. But again: the command is the normal command to take ownership (for $USER:$USER)

Comment: You mean, there is nothing much to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I, by mistake, ran the command:
>
> `sudo chown -R username:username /media/username/*`
>
> While I intended to run:
>
> `sudo chown -R username:username /media/username/586e1a3e-80c3-4057-81bz7-bbfe7662c6ff`

These two can be identical, if the only mounted media/disk partition was just `586e1a3e-80c3-4057-81bz7-bbfe7662c6ff`.

If, however, other media were mounted at the time of running the first command, then `*` will normally be expanded by the shell to all non-hidden(*Not starting with a dot `.`*) files(*media or otherwise*) and therefore they will be affected by that command equally.

> How can I revert the permissions of the `/media/username` directory
> and its contents?

This directory was not and can not be affected by your first command (*Under the current versions of Ubuntu which inhibit hard/soft links to parent directories*) and therefore, doesn't need reverting whatsoever.

Also, other than currently mounted media, that directory usually has no contents by default.